# AndroidAnnotations and context menu in ListActivity

Tags: android, contextmenu, listactivity, android-annotations

I have an activity inherited from **ListActivity** and using AndroidAnnotations. While `.onListItemClick` works fine, context menu for the list item does not appear at all and even `.onCreateContextMenu` isn't called, but `.onListItemClick` fires after a long tap to list item. Here's my code:

```
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.places)
@EActivity(R.layout.places)
public class PlacesPicker extends ListActivity {

    private static String[] DATA_SOURCE = { PlacesDB.PLACE_NAME, PlacesDB.PLACE_DESC };
    private static int[] DATA_DESTINATION = { R.id.place_name, R.id.place_desc };

    public static ListView lv;

    @Bean
    PlacesDB db;

    Cursor cursor;

    @AfterInject
    public void init() {

        cursor = db.getPlaces(null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.place_item, cursor, DATA_SOURCE, DATA_DESTINATION);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();

        registerForContextMenu(lv);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                // It works fine
                // It works even after long tap instead of context menu!
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OptionsItem
    public void addPlace(){
                // It works OK too
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PlaceEditor_.class));

    }

    public void editPlace() {
        // ...skipped for brevity...
    }

    public void deletePlace() {
            // ...skipped...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                // This isn't ever called!
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.place_options, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // ...skipped...
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it! It was my own mistake: the `.init()` method must be annotated as `@AfterViews`, not as `@AfterInject`. It works like this: the **ListActivity** has a default **ListView** when created, then my bean **PlacesDB** is injected, after that fires `@AfterInject` method, i.e. `.init()` where the *default* **ListView** is registered for context menu, and *after that* my `R.layout.places` is set as content view for activity with *another* **ListView** which is *not* registered! So, changing annotation to `@AfterViews` makes `.init()` to run *after* `.setContentView(R.layout.places)` and then my own **ListView** from the layout is registered for context menu and everything begins to work :)